# Cumulative MySQL queries. How do I use multiple FROM statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some queries that are working well separately. Each of these queries relates to a different type of filter that a user may want to use when searching for results. Each of the queries gets exactly the same columns from the 5 tables in the database. What I would like to acheive is to use the filters cumulatively (ie, the abililty to search by a date period and by name etc, or by place and status)

What I am having trouble with is putting the individual queries together so that the results of one can be used as the starting point for the next query. I have read up on intersecting and how that is acheived in MySQL, but I don't think I want this, because in order to do this, I would have to run all my queries in full and then find the intersections which would take a lot of time.

I want to start with the query that I think is going to be smallest and then get the results, then use those results as the starting point for the next query. This could be the difference between the next query having to search multiple tables for 5000 records for each filter, or honing down the result to less than 200 queries and the next query already having a laid out table to work from.

I thought I may be able to use syntax such as:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE DATE(trans_date) 
    BETWEEN DATE(from_date) AND DATE(to_date) 
        FROM (SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 
        WHERE name = "Joe" AND lname = "Bloggs")) 
WHERE status = "Open"
```

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Comment: Why dont you just make a syntax like SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE DATE(trans_date) BETWEEN DATE(from_date) AND DATE(to_date) AND name = "Joe" AND lname = "Bloggs" AND status = "Open" ... There is no need for subqueries imho

Comment: I agree with Hans.  This sounds like a case of premature optimization.  You shouldn't have to nest queries like that for performance means.  If your tables have appropriate indexes, you can put all the criteria in one WHERE clause and the query optimizer will be able to formulate an optimal filtering strategy.

Comment: If you really have five tables with exactly the same columns I think you have a data modelling issue.  Is the data sharded (different keys in each table) or overlapping (same keys in each table but different columns / values for non-key data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 1):

In general - yes. Though most RDBMS want an alias for each subquery within a FROM iirc, something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT *
 FROM ....
 WHERE ...
) AS sub1
```